# Get each element value inside elements array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find elements value inside elements array. Note, that there are many `<a>` elements, but only one `<span id="attendees">` inside one `<a>`.

As following example:

HTML:

```
<a id="meetingItem_{{meeting.id}}" onclick="AuthorityCheck()"> Item

      <span id="attendees" style="visibility:collapse;" >{{meeting.attendees}}</span>
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function AuthorityCheck(){

          var items = $('*[id^="meetingItem_"]');
          for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
               var people = items[i].id.indexOf("attendees"); // I need to find span value here, but get undefined.
          }
    }
```

It can be with jQuery as well, but I would prefer Javascript. :)

Comment: Why not just `document.getElementById('attendees')`?

Comment: A span doesn't have `value`

Comment: Unless the HTML was made incorrectly, there should only be *one* `id="attendees"` on the entire page.

Comment: @ Taurib: An `id` value must be used on only **one** element on the entire page. It looks like you have multiple `meetingItem_X` elements, each of which has an `id="attendees"` in it. That's invalid HTML, you'll need to fix it (for instance, us a class).

Comment: Thank you for the id remark, I'll use them only as unique values :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function AuthorityCheck()
{
      var items = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="meetingItem_"]');
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
      {
           var people = document.getElementById("attendees").innerHTML;  
      }
}
```

This solution is fully vanilly and uses no jQuery. innerHTML is uses because it gives the content back in every browser. If there is HTML that shouldn't be retrieved.  you should use innerText or textContent. Change the line to this:

```
 var people = document.getElementById("attendees").textContent || document.getElementById("attendees").innerText;
```

**On a side note:** `Id` is unique for the *complete `DOM tree`*. That means if you have multiple `a` elements with attendees `span` in it. The code will not work properly since there are multiple `spans` with `id` = `attendees`. You can circumnavigate this by using attributes or classes.

```
 <span data-type="attendees" style="visibility:collapse;" >{{meeting.attendees}}</span>
```

```js
function AuthorityCheck()
{
      var items = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="meetingItem_"]');
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
      {
           var people = items[i].querySelectorAll("span[data-type='attendees']")[0].innerHTML;  
      }
}
```

Comment: `getElementById` is a method of `Document.prototype`, but not of `Element.prototype`

Comment: Great, that second AuthorityCheck example was the way I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
var people = document.getElementById("attendees").textContent;
```

?

Or the cross-browser-friendly:

```
var people = $("#attendees").text();
```

Comment: `textContent` isn't portable.

Comment: @Barmar What does "portable" mean?

Comment: @Barmar It's [portable enough for me](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent#Browser_compatibility), but I've provided an alternative now.

Comment: I must have it confused with something else, I thought it didn't work in Firefox.

Comment: @Oriol: "Portable" means "works anywhere".  In this case, it means `.textContent` only works in *modern* browsers and not in *all* browsers.  [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) works in *every* version of *every* browser except IE.  It only works in IE 9+.

Comment: @A.Wolff `innerHTML` should only be used when you specifically want to treat the content as HTML. Probably not an issue here because the span (presumably) only contains numbers, but if it contained ampersands and the like, `innerHTML` would be a very poor choice.

Comment: @Barmar You may have been thinking of `innerText`, which is IE-only.

Comment: @JLRishe Yeah, that's what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

If the the item has the 'attendess' id just take the value of that element, if your element is an span you can store your value in a `data-attribute`:

**JS**

```
 function AuthorityCheck(){
      var items = $('*[id^="meetingItem_"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
          if (items[i].id.indexOf("attendees") !== -1) {
            var people = items[i].getAttribute('data-value');
          }
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="attendees" data-value="your value">
```

Comment: `span` doesn't have `.value`.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, I did not noticed that was an span

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
var people = [];
$('*[id^="meetingItem_"]').each(function (index) {
    people[index] = $(this).find('span#attendees').html();
});
```

Comment: Again, IDs must be unique on document context so this could be a workaround regarding invalid HTML markup BUT OP would have better to use valid HTML markup in first place

Comment: yes i know but this is how used Taurib. I would like to use class or data-